# PHP returning less results than mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysql query that when I run in the mysql console returns 4 results, and are exactly what I need, but when I try it in PHP I only get 2 results.  Does anything look wrong with my PHP?  I have echoed the query to a string, pasted that into the console, and it gives me what I need as well.  When I echo the number of rows that are returned, it is 2.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['source'])){
    $source = $_POST['source'];
}

if(isset($_POST['destination'])){
    $destination = $_POST['destination'];
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Airport Tracking";
$table ="Flights";
$flag = 0;

// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['source']) && isset($_POST['destination'])){
$columns= $mysqli -> query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");

$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM Flights a
    JOIN Flights b
    ON a.Destination = b.Source
    AND {$source} = a.Source
    AND {$destination} = b.Destination";

$result = $mysqli -> query($sql);


if($result == FALSE){
    echo "<br><b>Incorrect input</b>";
    $flag = 1;
}
else if($result->num_rows == 0){
    echo "<br><b>Returned no results</b>";
    $flag = 1;
}

}

$array = array();
$i = 0;

if(isset($_POST['source']) && $flag == 0){
 // Display results
echo "<table>";
echo "<thead><tr>";
while ($row = $columns -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    echo "<th>" .$row['Field']. "</th>";
    $array[] = $row['Field'];
}
echo "</tr></thead>";

while ($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    while ($i < sizeof($array)) {
        echo "<td>" .utf8_encode($row[$array[$i]]). "</td>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $i = 0;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` and then `foreach ($row as $value)` instead of that complicated `while` loop to print the columns?

Comment: Can you point me to a page that demonstrates how to do so?  Also, would that change the results?

Comment: No, it wouldn't change the results. I can't see anything wrong. Are you sure you're connecting to the same database when you run the query by hand as when the PHP script runs?

Comment: Yes I am.  And that's why it's driving me so crazy.

Comment: What is the datatype of `source` and `destination`?

Comment: What happens if you simplify the query to something like `SELECT * FROM Flights`?

Comment: The type is int.  When I do that query all of the rows  are displayed.

Comment: You said that `$result->num_rows` is returning 2, right? So the problem isn't with how you display the results, the query is really just returning 2 rows instead of 4. There's no reason why a query would return a different number of rows when called from PHP than when you do it by hand.

Comment: Correct, it is giving me 2.  That is why I am so baffled.  I am running out of ideas on what could be the source of the issue.

Comment: Are you testing `phpmyadmin` to test your query?

Comment: I am using the console.  I am running a local server using XAMPP.  I just checked my console and it has the correct results, but under further investigation it is actually 2 rows.  Each row is a set of two rows joined.  When I display it using PHP it only shows the first part of the joined row.

Comment: Maybe I need to find a way to output rows of a joined table?

Comment: Since you're joining a table with itself, you're getting duplicate column names. But an associative array can only have one element with a given name.

Comment: Also, you're only printing column headings for one set of columns, not both.

Comment: I can fix the column headings easily but how do I fix the duplicate column issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `SELECT *` when you're returning columns from a self-join. The columns in both `a` and `b` are the same, but you need to give them distinct names. So use something like:

```
SELECT a.source AS start, 
       a.flightno AS flight1, 
       a.destination AS connection, 
       b.flightno AS flight2, 
       b.destination AS destination
```

Then in your code that displays the table, do:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($col) . "</td>";
    }
}
```

You'll also need to change the code that displays the column headings to use headings corresponding to these columns that you've selected, instead of getting them from `SHOW COLUMNS` (because that will just get one set of column names).

Comment: Thank you so much, I am about to change my code and see if it works.  Will report back in a few minutes.

Comment: "SELECT a.col1 AS src_col1, a.col2 AS src_col2
 b.col1 AS dst_col1, b.col2 AS dst_col2
 FROM Flights a
 JOIN Flights b
 ON a.Destination = b.Source
 AND '{$source}' = a.Source
 AND '{$destination}' = b.Destination";

Comment: That is the string I am using for my query.  It doesn't seem to work.  I probably formatted it wrong.

Comment: Did you replace `col1`, `col2`, etc. with the real column names?

Comment: Whoops... Will do that.
Edit: This is the query string I have used but I still don't think it is formatted correctly.

Comment: "SELECT a.source AS src_col1, a.source AS src_col2
 b.destination AS dst_col1, b.destination AS dst_col2
 FROM Flights a
 JOIN Flights b
 ON a.Destination = b.Source
 AND '{$source}' = a.Source
 AND '{$destination}' = b.Destination"

Comment: Why are you selecting `a.source` twice?

Comment: You're missing the comma after `src_col2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74305/discussion-between-user3019324-and-barmar).

Answer (score -1):

You need back ticks around field-names that have spaces. you need to change these lines like this:

```
AND `{$source}` = a.Source
AND `{$destination}` = b.Destination";
```

Comment: The name of the table is `Flights`. `a` and `b` are aliases.

Comment: That's not right, either. `{$source}` and `{$destination}` don't contain field names, they're literal values that come from the POST parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately this gave the same results.

Comment: Didn't you see the part of his question where he said that he echoed the query and then executed it by hand?

Comment: Yeah that's another thing.  I don't think it's the query at all that's formatted wrong.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry, your right.
and yes I saw that part but usually when you use `PhpMyAdmin` to test your query, it back ticks things and coats strings automatically. I thought that the problem happens there